# Storing yaml into AWS SSM store

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-ssm

I have the following YAML file(sample content in the below section) which I would like to store in AWS-SSM. Each property in YAML should be kept as a key/value pair in the AWS parameter store.

```
 doe: "a deer, a female deer"
 ray: "a drop of golden sun"
 pi: 3.14159
 xmas: true
 french-hens: 3
 calling-birds:
   - huey
   - dewey
   - louie
   - fred
 xmas-fifth-day:
   calling-birds: four
   french-hens: 3
   golden-rings: 5
   partridges:
     count: 1
     location: "a pear tree"
   turtle-doves: two
```

In SSM it should be stored as,

```
name=xmas-fifth-day/partridges/count 
value=1

name=xmas-fifth-day/partridges/location 
value=a pear tree

etc etc.
```

There is a library for [json2SSM](https://github.com/b-b3rn4rd/json2ssm) it would be great if we have one for yaml2SSM or if we can able to achieve it using was AWS-CLI command is exceptionally grateful.

AWS SSM PUT_PARAMETERS support `yaml-input` but the format YAML is different than the one I have. If converting the YAML to a different one is the only solution then do we have any simple way to convert it? Any python/js/java library which converts the format?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert yaml to json with `yq`.

```bash
# install on mac 
brew install yq
```

`yq -o=json ssm-input.yml | json2ssm put-json --json-file /dev/stdin`

---

- Convert yaml to json `yq -o=json ssm-input.yml`
- `json2ssm put-json --json-file /dev/stdin` send json file to SSM with `json2ssm`

It supports `encryption` as well.
See: https://github.com/b-b3rn4rd/json2ssm/blob/master/cmd/json2ssm/main.go#L25

Updated command with encryption:

`yq -o=json ssm-input.yml | json2ssm put-json --json-file /dev/stdin --encrypt`

---

Update 2:

```
{
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "Name": "/path/to/base_linux_ami",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "ami-aminumber"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on your answer a bit? we cannot use json2ssm since the library doesn't support encryption also it was not touched for more than 3-years.

Comment: @VelNaga I update my answer with explain with `json2ssm`  encryption details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. How it inserts the value into SSM? one by one or batch-insert?

Comment: one by one https://github.com/b-b3rn4rd/json2ssm/blob/44a84018e03504c63762a3833362e859ae3f6fbe/pkg/storage/storage.go#L297-L303

Comment: But this is not the correct way to insert 1000 keys. put_parameters supports -cli-input-json if possible we can pipe the JSON directly

Comment: Also, can we install json2ssm via "apt-get" or "apk?

Comment: `--cli-input-json` file format is completely different. Yes you can send multiple parameter with single command. Your input json file needs to be convert in this file format. In my opinion using json2ssm is easier then to convert json input to cli-input-json format.

Comment: They provided how to install cli on their github page: https://github.com/b-b3rn4rd/json2ssm/tree/master#installation 
on linux firstly install go then you can install with `go get`